# Update information as needed

Tags: php, javascript

On the page I have a list of HTML-elements, each element has its status:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class='status'>ok</span>
        <span class='content'>content1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='status'>not ok</span>
        <span class='content'>content2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='status'>ok</span>
        <span class='content'>content3</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This list is very big.

I need to update the status (without reloading the page).

What are the ways to do this?

I wanted to use AJAX. And periodically poll the database and get out status, etc.
What could be more options?

**Update1:**

I think that the use of Ajax in this way is not very good: the status change very rarely, and a list of objects is large.

Answer (score 1):

Without reloading the page? AJAX seems to be current best practice. Or you can use an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I think AJAX is the best choice for you. You can use [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) (a javascript framework) for [AJAX functionality](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).